# Find cause of error when launching PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I've been using PowerShell for years, but recently it has started displaying an error when it starts up:

```
PowerShell 7.2.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.

https://aka.ms/powershell
Type 'help' to get help.

MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Reverse" with "1" argument(s): "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'array')"

MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Reverse" with "1" argument(s): "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'array')"
```

I've tried commenting out everything in `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`, but the error persists.  I figure the error is due to an installed module, but I'm at a loss as to how to narrow down which one is causing the issue.  Does anyone have a suggestion as to how to approach this?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `$Error[0].ErrorRecord.ScriptStackTrace` to see the source of the error. You likely have a call to `[array]::Reverse(...)` in one of the profile scripts (yes, there's more than 1). Find all applicable file paths with `$PROFILE |Select *host* |Format-List`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks for the reply.  The command `$PROFILE |Select *host* |Format-List` lists 4 potential profile scripts, only one of which exists.  I tried placing `$Error[0].ErrorRecord.ScriptStackTrace` at the top of this script and launching a new shell, but nothing was displayed (other than the existing error).  I also tried commenting everything out in this script, and relaunching, but the error persists.

Comment: It's `$Error[0].ScriptStackTrace` in version `7.1.5`. Run  the following code snippet in launched `pwsh`  window: `$Error | % { $_;$_.ScriptStackTrace }`

Comment: @JosefZ This worked, thanks!  Turns out it was the Persistent-History module that was causing the problem.  That module hasn't been updated since 2015.